# Does ADFS 3.0 federation work with non-ADFS identity providers?

Tags: adfs, federation

Can ADFS 3.0 delegate authentication to a non-ADFS identity provider through a federation trust relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We see customers regularly interop with multiple identity providers. These span across traditional federation vendors as we as cloud IDP's as well as cloud SaaS apps.

Check out http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2735.ad-fs-content-map.aspx#Interoperability_with_Non-Microsoft_Products. Some of the content is old, but the concepts are pretty much the same.

Thanks // Sam (@MrADFS)

Comment: You can also go custom. I've just developed a custom STS that ADFS delegates authentication to for a project.